# Looking for any information related to the CDC 1604 Co-Op Monitor

Tags: operating-system, cdc

The [CDC 1604](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_1604) Wikipedia page mentions a "Co-Op Monitor (developed by the users' organization)" used as the operating system. Has a contemporary description of its capabilities, e.g. a user manual, survived?

Unfortunately, [bitsavers.org](https://bitsavers.org/bits/CDC/) has nothing on CDC 1604 in the software section, and the [documentation section](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/cdc/1604/) has only CDC publications.

Comment: https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102636800 But it isn’t available to download there.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you; I'll attempt to inquire, but by the title it looks like just a specification document rather than a design or implementation document.

Comment: ['File-box 2, 49'](https://archives.lib.umn.edu/repositories/3/archival_objects/32852) in the U. of Minnesota archives. Alas, not online either.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but this [Oak Ridge Algol compiler manual](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4079348) does show how programs got run under the monitor.  It looks like the usual model of sequential batch OS.

Comment: @another-dave Thank you! Unfortunately, the Co-Op details are scarce there.  The "triangle" character is peculiar.

Comment: I think that's just documentation convention; it is described as a 7-9 punch. I've used a CDC system where 'control cards' were specific non-graphic hole combinations in column 1, different combinations for end-of-file, end-of-job, etc.

Comment: @another-dave The reason I'm asking is that the BESM-6 programming environment was influenced by, or has borrowed some features (object module format, linker, etc.) from Co-Op while porting the FORTRAN compiler. I was hoping to glean some details from Co-Op documents. The 7-9 punch is also familiar. In books about the BESM-6 system, it was rendered as small 7 over small 9. For example, `7÷9`IBM and `7÷9`CDC were used to switch interpretation of punched card encodings.

Comment: I guessed your real interest was the BESM-6, from the Wikipedia page on the 1604 !